# Navigator is not working at the bottom of highstocks chart

Tags: highcharts

I have a website running at https://weather.wesleyweisenberger.com and currently I am displaying temperature, pressure, and humidity in different graphs. The code for the graphs is:

```
$('#tempGraph').highcharts('StockChart', {
                series: tempSeries,
                xAxis: {
                    type: 'datetime',
                    showInNavigator: true,
                    tickInterval: 15 * 60 * 60,
                    minRange: 1
                },
                yAxis: [{
                    title: {
                        text: 'Temperature'
                    },
                    labels: {
                        format: '{value}°C'
                    }
                }],
                title: {
                    text: 'Temperature Over Time'
                },
                rangeSelector: {
                    buttons: [{
                        type: 'day',
                        count: 1,
                        text: '1d'
                    }, {
                        type: 'day',
                        count: 7,
                        text: '1w'
                    }, {
                        type: 'month',
                        count: 1,
                        text: '1m'
                    }, {
                        type: 'year',
                        count: 1,
                        text: '1y'
                    }, {
                        type: 'all',
                        text: 'All'
                    }]
                }
            })
```

But unfortunately the navigator is not working at the bottom of the page, it works in some places such as on my phone, but it does not seem to work in chrome. Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: Console reveals the following error on your website: `Uncaught ReferenceError: Highcharts is not defined`. It occurs because you import `highcharts-more.js` script before `highstock.js`. Please fix it and well see if the problem still exists.

Comment: I just fixed this, but it still does not seem to work...

Comment: Well I just refreshed it and its working!